# How much damage does each piece of armor absorb?

Tags: the-gold-factory

I've noticed just in the first tier of armor that even though all armor costs the same, they are not equal in damage reduction. How much damage can each type of armor absorb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After analyzing the source code, I've figured out the exact numbers:

- Helmets absorb 1% of damage per upgrade for a total maximum protection of 4%
- Chestplates absorb 2% of damage per upgrade for a total maximum protection of 8%
- Pants absorb 1.5% of damage per upgrade for a total maximum protection of 6%
- Boots absorb 0.5% of damage per upgrade for a total maximum protection of 2%

The price at the beginning is the same because the price formula is `(armorRating*armorRating)*1000+1000`, where `armorRating` is the current protection percentage that you have for that armor type (multiplied by 100).